# Determine when user logs via a regular login or via a remember_me

Tags: flask, flask-login

I would like to store the time and date for each user log in.
Putting this code into the regular login view is simple.

The problem arises when [Flask-Login's remember_me](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#remember-me) is used - login is no longer called giving me no way of knowing if the login is fresh.

I have tried the user_logged_in, user_login_confirmed signals provided by Flask-Login:

```
 def  user_logged_in_callback(*args, **kwargs):
      import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()

 user_logged_in.connect(user_logged_in_callback, app)
 user_login_confirmed.connect(user_logged_in_callback, app)
```

user_logged_in is only called on regular logins and user_login_confirms doesn't seem to be called at all.

Answer (score 4):

Getting the user again after login is called "user load" and is not really a login event, it's just the same user still.  [There is a signal for it](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login.py#L909), however it's not documented.

You can use the `user_loaded_from_cookie` signal:

```
from flask_login import user_loaded_from_cookie

user_loaded_from_cookie.connect(user_login_callback, app)
```

---

`user_login_confirm` is for when a login is refreshed - a fresh login is required and the user re-enters their password.

---

If all you want to do is record when a user last visited the site, you can just use `app.before_request`, you don't need to deal with the login events.

```
@app.before_request
def track_user():
    if current_user.is_authenticated():
        current_user.last_seen = datetime.utcnow()
```